# Instanciando form para bloquear button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou instanciando um form com um único `textbox` apenas para colocar a senha para liberar a ação do botão.

O botão tem função de exportar os dados contidos no `datagridview` para uma planilha no Excel, estou tentando fazer desta maneira:

```
private void btnExportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formExportar form = new formExportar();
            form.ShowDialog();

            if (exportar.txtsenha.Text == "123")
            {
               //código para exportar arquivos para o excel
            }
            else
            {
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Senha incorreta", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
    }
```

No caso o `formExportar` é o form de autenticação onde insiro a senha, estou instanciando ele no form principal dessa forma:

```
public partial class TelaInicio : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        internal formExportar exportar = new formExportar();

    public TelaInicio(formExportar exportar)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.exportar = exportar;
    }
```

Porém pelo fato do botão `OK` que existe no `formExportar` não estar sendo executado acaba por não acontecer nenhuma ação.

Eu tentei também jogar todo o código de exportação no `formExportar` ao invés de deixar no form principal mas isso acaba ocasionando um erro pelo fato de não existir um `DataSource` naquele form, realmente não sei como proceder com isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta criar no btn para abrir a solicitação da senha:

```
        DialogResult resultado = new DialogResult();
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        resultado = f.ShowDialog();
        if (resultado == DialogResult.OK)
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("erro");
        }
```

e no form de exportação acrescentar dois botões, sendo um para ok e outro para sair.

Botão para tentar senha:

```
        if(textBox1.Text == "123")
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Senha incorreta");
        }
```

O que foi criado é semelhante a uma messagebox.